# optional input number with Zod schema

Tags: zod, use-form

Hi everyone I'm using for the first time Zod with React useForm and I'm having some trouble setting up a optional input.

**Zod Schema**

```ts
 discount: z
    .string()
    .optional()
    .transform((discount) =>
      discount === "" || discount === undefined ? undefined : parseInt(discount)
    )
    .pipe(z.number().nonnegative().max(100)),
```

**Input**

```ts
<FormInput<FormData, InputProps>
          id="DiscountFormCreateProduct"
          register={register}
          rules={{ required: false, valueAsNumber: true }}
          errors={errors}
          className="col-span-3"
          name="discount"
          labelText="Discount"
          label={"Discount number "}
          Formtype={FormElementType.INPUT}
          placeholder="Discount(Eg 5%)"
          isRequired={false}
          type="number"
          min={0}
          max={100}
        />
```

As you can see my input as rules not required but I still have the error messgae:
**Expected string, received nan**

thanks for your help

Comment: You might need to reduce your question some for us to be able to give a specific answer, but I suspect what is happening is that the schema is being handed a `number` not a `string`. Most likely, `useForm` is already calling `parseInt` internally and when the field is empty it's getting `NaN` (try `parseInt('')`). Then the `z.string` validation is failing. Incidentally, even if it were given a string, the schema as defined will fail to validate `''` and `undefined` because `z.number` in the `pipe` will fail. Try just `z.number().nonnegative().max(100).optional()` and see if that works?

Comment: I had the same issue. This is what I did as a solution
```price: z.number().positive().or(z.literal('')),
...
onChange={(evt) => {
  form.setValue(
    'price',
    Number.isNaN(evt.target.valueAsNumber) ? '' : evt.target.valueAsNumber
  )
}}
```